# How can I undo the change to repository after I did 'git checkout SHA'

Tags: git

If i do a `git checkout <SHA>` where `<SHA>` is some `commit-id` hash from `git log`, my repository returns to a previous stage.

How can I reverse the effect of `git checkout <SHA>`?

Comment: `git checkout HEAD` is useful for this.

Answer (score 5):

`git checkout` won't erase any of your repository's state. Simply run `git checkout` again on the desired refspec to get back where you want to be. If you started out on master, for example, run `git checkout master`.

If you don't know where you started from, you can use `git reflog` to examine all of the different states your repository has been in recently. If the erroneous `git checkout` was the last thing that you did, the second line of `git reflog` will be the last point that you were at.

Answer (score 2):

### Checkout previous commit

Git has a convenient shortcut to go back to the last commit you checked out:

```
git checkout -
```

i.e

```
[/tmp/popdemo(master)]$ git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
[/tmp/popdemo(develop)]$ git checkout -
Switched to branch 'master'
[/tmp/popdemo(master)]$ git checkout -
Switched to branch 'develop'
[/tmp/popdemo(develop)]$
```